# cruisecontrol.net projecttrigger timeout

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have a project A ( DAL project ) that is relied upon by Projects B,C,D,E,F,G.

I currently have set up project triggers in the config of B,C,D,E,F,G and these are causing the projects to rebuild when project A successfully builds.

However, there is projects that are timing out as all the other projects are trying to be built at the same time.

Is there a way to stagger the build or get them to retry on failure of build?

Answer (score 1):

Put them all in the same queue.  CCNet only allows one project to build per queue.